# Querying value of xml file using xmlstarlet with namspace

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

using this xml:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0">
    <id>5555</id>
    <filename>product2</filename>
    <name>prodigy</name>
    <versionNumber>6.5.511</versionNumber>
    <versionLabel>6.5.5110</versionLabel>
</application>
```

this command does not work, returns nothing:

```
xml sel -t -c "/application/versionLabel" application.xml
```

however, removing the xmlns attribute from application does work.   why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0" -t -m "/x:application/x:versionLabel" -c . -n file
```

or (using default namespace) :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/_:application/_:versionLabel" file
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
<versionLabel xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0">6.5.5110</versionLabel>
```